# Problema al crear input con un bucle en vue

Tags: vue.js, formularios, bucle-for, elementui

estoy intentando crear un formulario dinámico con Vue usando `v-for`. Utilizo la librería Element-ui.
El problema viene que al crear el formulario lo pinta bien pero a la hora de escribir en él no me deja hacerlo.

Formulario:

```
       <el-form>
          <div v-for="field in schema.fields" :key="field.model">
            <span class="label">{{ field.label }}</span>
            <el-input v-model="form[field.model]"></el-input>
          </div>
        </el-form>
```

Tanto el array `schema.fields` como el objeto `form` se rellenan dinamicamente dependiendo de que estemos consultando.

Un ejemplo como quedaría sería:

schema.fields

```
[
  { 
   type: 'input',
   inputType: text,
   label: name,
   model: name,
  },
  { 
   type: 'input',
   inputType: text,
   label: lastName,
   model: lastName,
  },
  { 
   type: 'input',
   inputType: date,
   label: date,
   model: date,
  },
]
```

form

```
 { 
   name: '',
   lastName: '',
   date: '',
  }
```

Si quito la etiqueta `<el-input>` y punto `<input>` funciona bien y me deja escribir en los campos.

Un saludo y gracias por ayudarme :)

Comment: Hola en la documentación indica: "Input es un componente controlado, siempre muestra el valor de enlace Vue.

Bajo circunstancias normales, el evento "input" debe ser manejado. Su handler debe actualizar el valor de enlace del componente (o usar v-model). De lo contrario, el valor del cuadro de entrada no cambiará.

No admite modificadores v-model. "

Intenta usar value en lugar de v-model.

Comment: No, eso no funciona... Gracias por comentar pero sigue sin dejarme escribir

Comment: En lo personal no utilizo los inputs de element porque creo que no es necesario, un poco de tailwind y todo es mejor, menos capas de abstracción, tal vez lo que vale la pena de element son otras cosas, pero con inputs siempre he tenido problemas. Igualmente con chakra vue, un saludo.

Comment: Si, voy a dejar de usar sus inputs porque no facilitan nada... Dan mas problemas de lo que soluciona. Un saludo